# Ordering of nodes after in memory update with mem:insert-child() is inconsistent

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using Ryan Dew's xquery module (https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations) with MarkLogic v8.0-5 to perform in-memory updates to a document.

The following code sample replicates the problem I experience when I use the insert-child() operation. Elements inserted with insert-child() should reflect the insertion order, but I find they do not. In other words, the elements should be ordered one, two, three, four, five in the output. Instead, the order appears to be random.

```
let $x := <root><original-container><one/><two/><three/><four/><five/></original-container><new-container/></root>
let $tx := mem:copy($x)
let $_ :=
   for $item in $x/original-container/*
   return ( 
      xdmp:set( $tx, mem:delete($tx, $item) ) , 
      xdmp:set( $tx, mem:insert-child($tx, $x/new-container, $item) )
   )

return mem:execute( $tx )
```

I may be misusing the code library--in particular, I am creating a transaction map and then resetting it with `xdmp:set()` after each `insert-child()` operation. Perhaps this is not correct?

Comment: Both delete and insert-child accept sequences as last argument. Have you considered deleting and inserting the items all at once? That will likely perform better too..

Comment: That is actually the workaround I am using, but there are some cases where it is hard to collect all the nodes together for a single insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize, as this was a bug in my code. An expression was returning the nodes in "document order" and across documents that can appear random. I've committed a fix and more details can be found at [the ticket on GitHub.](https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations/issues/16)